# Control iPad screen time settings remotely on the web

Tags: ipad, screen-time

I would like to know if it is possible to control the "Screen Time" settings of an iPad via the Apple Account website.

Please note that:

1. I want to control the settings via a browser.  There is no iPhone or iMac. The iPad is the only Apple device I have.
2. As such, there is no need / not applicable to set up "family sharing" etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you currently cannot manage Screen Time settings from the web (iCloud.com or else), you have to use Settings or System Settings app for that.

You can still use the iPad itself to setup and manage Screen Time settings (see [Use Screen Time on your iPhone, iPad and iPod Touch](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT208982) and [Set time limits for apps and websites in Screen Time on Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchl630bc02f/mac) for more info).

Comment: I just learned how to do that on ipad itself, unfortunately that is not possible over the web, which means I cannot change the settings remotely, without touching the device... :-)